# How to get direct permanent link to public image on Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I have Google Photo public album and I want to receive direct links for photos form this album. This links I'll use on my blog web pages. How I can to do it?

P.S.: I know that Picasa Web Albums had this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time Google actively changes its image service behavior. Now, there is not any algorithms how to receive direct and permanent links to your shared photos. The URLs are received by the right-button click, like `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/(LONGLONGCODE...)=w800-h600-no`, are temporary and live one-two days and then will be closed.

You can try new Google service - [Google Archive Album](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/). This service was created as holder for albums from the deleted Picasa service. But it contains photos and albums from Google Photo too. The Google Archive Album have two greats advantages:

- links are much shorter the from those of Google Photos,
- this links are permanent!

For working with Google Archive Album you need to follow rules:

1. create standard (NOT PUBLIC) album in Google Photos.
2. go to [Google Archive Album](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/) and make sure that you see the new album.
3. add to album required photos and only now change its type to the public by creating the shared link to it.
4. again go to [Google Archive Album](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/), open your album.
5. click on first photo.
6. right-clink on photo image and copy link to the clipboard.
7. insert received link where you need.
8. repeat steps 5-7 for others photos.
9. *voilà!*

But how long time Google Archive Album will working I don't know :(

**P.S.:** If you don't know - URL links from Google Photos and Google Archive Album can be tuned. For detail reads the [special site](https://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/Home/Picasa-FAQ/google-photos-1/how-to/how-to-get-a-direct-link-to-an-image).

Comment: Other answer by @randy. https://support.google.com/photos/thread/120633827/which-link-to-use-to-link-to-google-photos-reliably?hl=en&msgid=121263694

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: On Linux you can use `wget --no-cookies <shared gphoto url>` and parse result with `sed`.

I wrote a script that will do download and extract the permanent URL to image in its original size, here on GitHub: [get gphoto url](https://github.com/kalabic/get-gphoto-url)

There is also a second script in the same repo for creating HTML code for embedding into pages.

So many years later and this was still an interesting issue, so I am adding this answer here for others who Google for it. Fortunately Google did not change image service behavior in years and URLs the script on GitHub extracts work in my case for a while already.